# Dilemma trying to bind this code with the following code to make a password to enter program

Tags: python, function, passwords

Code:

```
print(Fore.CYAN +'Welcome To Manifest by Jysko#0420!')
print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, end='')
tools = '''Tools: 
webchecker
portscanner
webhook spammer'''
print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, end='')
print('TOOLS ARE CASE SENSITIVE!')
print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, end='')
print(tools)

secret_word = 'Blaze4'
guess = ''
print(Fore.YELLOW, end='')
guess = input('Enter Password: ')
try:
  if guess != secret_word:
    print(Fore.RED, end='')
    error = print('ACCESS DENIED')
  else:
    print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
    print('ACCESS GRANTED')
except:
  print('')
#NEW CODE IS ABOVE!
def funt():
  print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
  tool = input('Enter Desired Tool: ')
  print('')
  if tool == 'webchecker':
      try:
        print(Fore.CYAN, end='')
        site = input('Please Enter The Website Here: ')
        response = requests.get(site)
        requests.get(site)
        if response.status_code == 200:
          print('')
          print(f'{Fore.GREEN}Online!')
          sleep(1)
        else:
          print(f'{Fore.RED}Offline!')
          sleep(1)
      except:
        print('') 
  else:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Not A Tool!')
    print('')
while True:
   funt()
```

The section that says `#NEW CODE ABOVE` is what im trying to bind together. Starting from `secret_word` and then im trying to bind it with where `def funt():` starts.  By 'Bind' I mean I want to create a menu in a way a tool menu. I've tried many solutions still having a problem when you type in the wrong password still gives you access.  Must I mention I am learn to coding.

Comment: Put the call to `funt()` inside the `else:` block.

Comment: It works for access granted but if you put the wrong password I need it to loop the input again.

Comment: ik i need to add  `while` but idk how to add it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `while` loop around the code that asks for the password. When the correct password is entered you'll continue to the rest of the code.

```
while True:
    guess = input(Fore.YELLOW + 'Enter Password: ')
    try:
      if guess != secret_word:
        print(Fore.RED + 'ACCESS DENIED')
      else:
        print(Fore.GREEN, end='')
        print('ACCESS GRANTED')
        break # leave the loop
    except:
      print('')
```